# exist() method sqlite with ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

i'd like to create a method for "exist tuple?"

my old method with classic StartManagingCursor way was :

```
public boolean exist(long uid){
     boolean ex = false;

     Cursor c= db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + Person.PERSON_TABLE + " WHERE uid = "+ "'" + uid + "'", null);
            c.moveToFirst();
  int jcount = c.getInt(0);

  if (jcount >0){
            ex=true;                        
    }
     return ex;
```

}

now i wanna do this with ContentProvider for my sqlite db. 
how i can do this with query method of my contentprovider class?